# Not Serializable exception for SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jdbc

I am using Spring 4.3.2 and all of my DAO classes implement Serializable but I still get

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall

when starting the webapp in Tomcat 7.

My JdbcTemplate is defined as

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />    
</bean>
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, and the code that triggers the exception.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have changed the code so that SimpleJdbcCall objects are marked as transient which seems to have done the trick. I am not sure if that is the correct solution though, seems a bit of a cop out. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: You may have trouble in the future, You DAO are being serialized and when they get deserialized the transient attributes will be null